# C++ - Приватная структура - стек

Tags: c++, классы, struct, стек

Мне нужно создать **стек-структуру. Данные структуры должны быть private или protected.**

Вот содержание .h файла :

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    private:
    class MyStack
    {
        struct Stack
        {
            int data;

            struct Stack *Tail, *Head;
        };



    public:
        MyStack();
        ~MyStack();
        void ShowData();
        void AddData();
//эти еще не реализованы
        void ShowFirstItem();
        void ChangeItem();

    };
```

Вот .cpp файл:

```
#include "MyStack.h"


MyStack::MyStack()
{
    Stack *Stack1;
    Stack1->Tail = NULL;
    Stack1->Head = NULL;

}
MyStack::~MyStack()
{
    Stack *Stack1;
    while (Stack1 -> Head)
    {
        Stack1 -> Tail = Stack1 -> Head->Tail;
        delete Stack1 -> Head;
        Stack1->Head = Stack1-> Tail;
    }
}



void MyStack::AddData()
{
    Stack *Stack1=new Stack;
    Stack *temp = new Stack; //Выделяем память для нового элемента
    std::cin>>temp->data;
    temp->Tail= Stack1->Head; //Указываем, что следующий элемент это предыдущий
    Stack1->Head = temp; //Сдвигаем голову на позицию вперед
}
void MyStack::ShowData()
{
    Stack *Stack1 = new Stack;
    Stack *temp = new Stack; //Выделяем память для нового элемента
    std::cout << temp->data;
    temp->Tail = Stack1->Head; //Указываем, что следующий элемент это предыдущий
    Stack1->Head = temp; //Сдвигаем голову на позицию вперед
}
```

Ошибка возникает с инициализацией структуры. Пишет, что *была использована неинициализированная локальная переменная Stack1*.

Comment: Ну проще внести vector или forward_list в private область класса и определить для них методы присущие стеку.

Comment: По заданию нужна именно структура. А данные структуры должны быть private

Answer (score 1):

Как вы думаете что происходит в этом местe?

```
Stack *Stack1 = new Stack; //выделили место под новую переменную, но не заинициализировали его
....
temp->Tail= Stack1->Head; //Какое значение попадет в переменную temp->Tail?
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Я, честно, скопировал этот кусок с какой-то статьи и пытался адаптировать под свою программу. Там была функция в которую приходило значение наподобие `fun(List *New_list)`.

Я пробовал писать `Stack *Stack1;` ,но оно даже не компилировалось. Также требовало инициализацию.